# Missing CiviContribute voice in "Used for" Profile section

Tags: civicontribute, profile

I installed civicontribute and civimembership on my system. 
I have a pre-existing CIVICRM installation (ver. 5.12.1) on Joomla (3.9.5). 
My problem is that I can't associate the Profiles with the features of the contribution.
On profile section "used for" i have not civicontribute voice (nor i have the dropdown profile field in Contribution Page).

[image]

[image]

[image]

All profile fields are Contact and Individual.

Someone have a suggestion to resolve this issue?

Regards
Alessandro

Comment: Can you check resource url?

Comment: Hello, thank for your answer, i check resource url section, notice that url pah "CiviCRM Resource URL" is not absolute, may be this the cause of the issue? It is "administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/"

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the content of the page?

Comment: You may need to encrypt the website uri

Comment: I  add the screenshot of Resource URL page above

Comment: Ok, i tried to setup "CiviCRM Resource URL" as absolute path and enable "Force Secure URLs (SSL)" (i already have a SSL certificate for my website) but still not work. Whad do you mean exaclty with encrypt the website url?

Comment: can you check the browser console if you can see JS error on Profile page?

Comment: Also try clearing cache by navigation to Administer > System settings >> Cleanup Caches and Update Paths and say clean up

Comment: Hello, we clean the cache when we detect the problme the first time but it was no resolutive. For the javascript problems in backend on profile page we not detect anything, in contribution page (where dropdown missing) two error: "PHONE_TYPES[0] is undefined" and "CRM.UF.UFGroupCollection is not a constructor"